# LibGDX - What is the different between batch.begin(); and renderer.getBatch().begin();?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, spritebatch, tiled

I am learning LibGDX using Tiled Map. I came across the following two render methods.
The first one is simple one that I normally use.

However, I don't understand why we need the second one. Can I use batch.begin(); in method2 as well.

Thanks

Method 1

```
private Batch batch;

batch=new SpriteBatch();

public void Render(float delta){
......
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(......); 
    batch.end();
}
```

Method 2

```
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
private Batch batch;

public void Render(float delta){
......

        renderer.getBatch().begin();
        renderer.getBatch().draw(......);
        renderer.getBatch().end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the same. [Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/BatchTiledMapRenderer.java#L102) you can see that in case you do not supply a `Batch` to the renderer, it will create a `new Spritebatch()` itself. You can, however, also supply your own `Batch` to the renderer.

The `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer extends BatchTiledMapRenderer`, which [will call](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/renderers/BatchTiledMapRenderer.java#L241) `Batch.begin()` and `end()` itself, so you do not have to care about that.